# How to get image size from image url without downloading in swift

Tags: sdwebimage, swift3.2

I need image size from URL, When I set image from URL in UITableView 
   cell, Then I need a frame of UIImage so that I can set UIImageView 
   Frame size accordingly. I am using  below code

```
cell.imgPostedImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageArray[0]),placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"),options: 
SDWebImageOptions(rawValue: 0), completed: { (image, error, cacheType,imageURL) in
print(image?.size.height)                                        
cell.imgPostedImage.setNeedsLayout()
})
```